# How to display value in <h:selectOneMenu>

Tags: java, jsf, jsf-2

I have this menu:

```
<h:selectOneMenu value="#{ApplicationController.settings['SessionTTL']}">
    <f:selectItem itemValue="60" itemLabel="1 hour" />
    <f:selectItem itemValue="30" itemLabel="30 Minutes" />
    <f:selectItem itemValue="20" itemLabel="20 Minutes" />
    <f:selectItem itemValue="10" itemLabel="10 Minutes" />
    <f:selectItem itemValue="custom" itemLabel="Define custom value" />
    <f:ajax render="input" />
</h:selectOneMenu>&nbsp;
<h:panelGroup id="input">
    <h:inputText value="#{ApplicationController.settings['SessionTTL']}" rendered="#{ApplicationController.settings['SessionTTL'] == 'custom'}" required="true" />
</h:panelGroup>
```

The problem is that I cannot see the value into the menu label. When I click custom and I update it, I always get `1 hour`. If I modify this way the menu:

```
<h:selectOneMenu value="#{ApplicationController.settings['SessionTTL']}">
    <f:selectItem itemValue="#{ApplicationController.settings['SessionTTL']}" itemLabel="#{ApplicationController.settings['SessionTTL']}" />
    <f:selectItem itemValue="60" itemLabel="1 hour" />
    <f:selectItem itemValue="30" itemLabel="30 Minutes" />
    <f:selectItem itemValue="20" itemLabel="20 Minutes" />
    <f:selectItem itemValue="10" itemLabel="10 Minutes" />
    <f:selectItem itemValue="custom" itemLabel="Define custom value" />
    <f:ajax render="input" />
</h:selectOneMenu>&nbsp;
<h:panelGroup id="input">
    <h:inputText value="#{ApplicationController.settings['SessionTTL']}" rendered="#{ApplicationController.settings['SessionTTL'] == 'custom'}" required="true" />
</h:panelGroup>
```

I always get the first value into the menu label . Do you know why I cannot display the custom value into the menu label?

**PS** This is the complete source code:

```
<?xml version='1.0' encoding='UTF-8' ?>
<!DOCTYPE html PUBLIC "-//W3C//DTD XHTML 1.0 Strict//EN" "http://www.w3.org/TR/xhtml1/DTD/xhtml1-strict.dtd">
<html xmlns="http://www.w3.org/1999/xhtml" xml:lang="en" lang="en"    
      xmlns:h="http://java.sun.com/jsf/html"
      xmlns:f="http://java.sun.com/jsf/core"
      xmlns:ui="http://java.sun.com/jsf/facelets"
      xmlns:p="http://primefaces.org/ui">
    <h:head>
        <ui:insert name="header">           
            <ui:include src="header.xhtml"/>         
        </ui:insert>
    </h:head>
    <h:body>
        <h1><img src="resources/css/images/icon.png" alt="DX-57" /> Settings Center</h1>
        <!-- layer for black background of the buttons -->
        <div id="toolbar" style="margin: 0 auto; width:1180px; height:30px; position:relative;  background-color:black">
            <!-- Include page Navigation -->
            <ui:insert name="Navigation">           
                <ui:include src="Navigation.xhtml"/>         
            </ui:insert>
        </div>  
        <div id="logodiv" style="position:relative; top:35px; left:0px;"> 
            <h:graphicImage alt="General Settings"  style="position:relative; top:-20px; left:9px;"  value="resources/images/logo_general_settings.png" />
        </div>
        <div id="main" style="margin: 0 auto; width:1190px; height:700px; position:absolute;  background-color:transparent; top:105px">

            <div id="mainpage" style="margin: 0 auto; width:1190px; height:500px; position:absolute;  background-color:transparent; top:80px">
                <h:form id="settingsupdate">
                    <p:growl id="growl" showDetail="true" sticky="true" />

                    <div id="settingsdivone" style="width:550px; height:400px; position:absolute;  background-color:r; top:20px; left:1px">

                        <h:panelGrid columns="2">
                            <h:panelGroup>Application Timestamp Format</h:panelGroup>
                            <h:panelGroup>
                                <h:selectOneMenu value="#{GeneralController.settings['TimestampFormat']}">
                                    <f:selectItem itemValue="#{GeneralController.settings['TimestampFormat']}" itemLabel="#{GeneralController.settings['TimestampFormat']}" />
                                    <f:selectItem itemValue="yyyy-MM-dd-HH.mm.ss.ffffff" itemLabel="yyyy-MM-dd-HH.mm.ss.ffffff" />
                                    <f:selectItem itemValue="YYYY-MM-DD HH:MM:SS" itemLabel="YYYY-MM-DD HH:MM:SS" />
                                    <f:selectItem itemValue="YYYY-MM-DDThh:mm:ss.sTZD" itemLabel="YYYY-MM-DDThh:mm:ss.sTZD" />
                                    <f:selectItem itemValue="custom" itemLabel="Define custom value" />
                                    <f:ajax render="timestampformat" />
                                </h:selectOneMenu>&nbsp;
                                <h:panelGroup id="timestampformat">
                                    <h:inputText value="#{GeneralController.settings['TimestampFormat']}" rendered="#{GeneralController.settings['TimestampFormat'] == 'custom'}" required="true" />
                                </h:panelGroup>          
                            </h:panelGroup>

                            <h:panelGroup>Performance Tuning</h:panelGroup>
                            <h:panelGroup>
                                <h:selectOneMenu value="#{GeneralController.settings['PerformTunung']}">
                                    <f:selectItem itemValue="#{GeneralController.settings['PerformTunung']}" itemLabel="#{GeneralController.settings['PerformTunung']}" />
                                    <f:selectItem itemValue="10000" itemLabel="Less than 10000 table rows" />
                                    <f:selectItem itemValue="1000000" itemLabel="More than 1000000 table rows" />                                   
                                    <f:selectItem itemValue="custom" itemLabel="Define custom value" />
                                    <f:ajax render="performtuning" />
                                </h:selectOneMenu>&nbsp;
                                <h:panelGroup id="performtuning">
                                    <h:inputText value="#{GeneralController.settings['PerformTunung']}" rendered="#{GeneralController.settings['PerformTunung'] == 'custom'}" required="true" />
                                </h:panelGroup>
                            </h:panelGroup>  

                            <h:panelGroup>Application Initialization State</h:panelGroup>
                            <h:panelGroup>
                                <h:selectOneMenu value="#{GeneralController.settings['InitState']}">
                                    <f:selectItem itemValue="#{GeneralController.settings['InitState']}" itemLabel="#{GeneralController.settings['InitState']}" />
                                    <f:selectItem itemValue="1" itemLabel="Level 1" />
                                    <f:selectItem itemValue="2" itemLabel="Level 2" />
                                    <f:selectItem itemValue="3" itemLabel="Level 3" />
                                    <f:selectItem itemValue="custom" itemLabel="Define custom value" />
                                    <f:ajax render="initstate" />
                                </h:selectOneMenu>&nbsp;
                                <h:panelGroup id="initstate">
                                    <h:inputText value="#{GeneralController.settings['InitState']}" rendered="#{GeneralController.settings['InitState'] == 'custom'}" required="true" />
                                </h:panelGroup>
                            </h:panelGroup>  

                        </h:panelGrid>          

                    </div>   

                    <div id="settingsonedivtwo" style="width:350px; height:400px; position:absolute;  background-color:transparent; top:20px; left:400px">

                    </div>   

                    <div id="settingstwodivthree" style="width:150px; height:60px; position:absolute;  background-color:transparent; top:380px; left:800px">
                        <p:commandButton value="Save Settings" id="ajax" actionListener="#{GeneralController.updateDBSettings}" rendered="true" update="growl,settingsupdate"/>
                    </div> 
                </h:form> 
            </div>  
        </div>
    </h:body>
</html>
```

Comment: Your `ApplicationController` bean should have ViewScope (at least), in your commandButton or commandLink, set an ajax tag that will render the input panelGroup. Also, the panelGroup should be outside your form, or else the empty value from the inner inputText will be sent to the server to fill `{ApplicationController.settings['SessionTTL']`attribute.

Comment: I changed the scope. If I put `panelGroup` outside the form how I can update the data into the DB? For now the data is updated as it should. The problem is the label of the select menu.

Comment: If there is more code inside your panelGroup and you just want to fill the inputText, use JavaScript. I don't know why you want to use the same attribute for 2 UI components in the __same form__ that can send different data to the server, this will mislead to odd behavior in your site.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Based in your update, you just need to update the inputText using JavaScript, no need to add the rendered attribute, nor an panelGroup wrapping the value.

```html
<script type="text/javascript">
    function updateInputText(ddlChanged, inputTextId) {
        var realId= "settingsupdate:" + inputTextId;
        document.getElementById("realId").value = 
            ddlChanged.options[ddlChanged.selectedIndex].text;
    }
</script>
<h:form id="settingsupdate">
    <!-- another components... -->
    <h:selectOneMenu id="ddlMyOptions" value="#{GeneralController.settings['InitState']}"
        onchange="updateInputText(this, 'txtMyText');">
        <f:selectItem itemValue="1" itemLabel="Level 1" />
        <f:selectItem itemValue="2" itemLabel="Level 2" />
        <f:selectItem itemValue="3" itemLabel="Level 3" />
        <f:selectItem itemValue="custom" itemLabel="Define custom value" />
    </h:selectOneMenu>
    <h:inputText id="txtMyText" />
</h:form>
```